# How to create a raster from xyz file format

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation

I have xyz points. I have imported these XYZ points into QGIS and need to create a raster from these points. I have used the raster interpolation plugin and I used IDW as the interpolation method. I got this raster (The following snapshot). Why it is like this? How I can fix it?

[image]

The average distance between points are 15m. In the above snapshot, the distance coefficient p is 2.

In the below snapshot, the distance coefficient p is 15. I have to mentioned that I used the IDW method.

[image]

What distance coefficient p. I need to use.

Any Idea?

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: These black and white points are the points which i have created the raster based on . why this is like that?

Comment: The radius that you have used for IDW is obviously rather small. Technically the raster is OK but you may want to adjust your parameters.

Comment: Can you please tell us something about your data (source)?

Answer (score 4):

The IDW method calculates weighted average of the given points. The weight is inverse proportional to the distance between grid point and known point. P is used in the weight as a power of the distance. So the more you increase P, the less affect has a point to its environment. The usual value for P is 2.
I would reduce the resolution of the output raster to the average distance of points and I would reduce P to 0.5-1.5 to have fewer local peeks.

An example P=2

[image: P=2]

And P=0.5

[image: P=0.5]

You may give a try to triangle interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

try to use "rasterize (from vector to raster) instead of interpolation (if you open it as text layer firstly you need to save it as layer file)